# php - try, catch, and retry

Tags: php, try-catch

Sometimes my code breaks and it is out of my control

How would I do the following?

```
try {
//do my stuff
}
catch {
//sleep and try again
}
```

The code isn't that much, so it's all one function, so I didn't want to make and call another function if I didn't have to

Comment: How many times do you want to retry the same operation? Why would you want to retry an operation that fails? What exactly is out of your control?

Comment: A couple times. I use a third party api that comes down for a couple minutes every once in a while.

Comment: @oliakaoil, if that "Why would you want to retry an operation that fails?" was asked in the general sense: in case of a *recoverable error* the ex. handler could fix things up and let the normal flow proceed by retrying. In fact, there's even an RFC for `retry` now: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/retry-keyword

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
function exception_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ) {
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline);
}
set_error_handler("exception_error_handler");

$NUM_OF_ATTEMPTS = 5;
$attempts = 0;

do {

    try
    {
        executeCode();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $attempts++;
        sleep(1);
        continue;
    }
    
    break;

} while($attempts < $NUM_OF_ATTEMPTS);

function executeCode(){
    echo "Hello world!";
}
```

Here, we perform a `do...while` loop so that the code is executed at least once. If the `executeCode()` function experiences an error, it will throw an `Exception` which the `try...catch` block will capture. The `catch` block will then increment the variable `$attempt` by one and call `continue` to test the `while` condition for the next iteration. If there have already been five attempts, the loop will exit and the script can continue. If there is no error, i.e. the `continue` statement from the `catch` block is not executed, the loop will `break`, thus finishing the script.

Note the use of the `set_error_handler` function taken from [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php). We do this so that all errors within the `executeCode()` function are caught, even if we don't manually throw the errors ourselves.

If you believe your code may fail numerous times, the [`sleep()`](https://www.php.net/sleep) function may be beneficial before the `continue` statement. 'Slowing' down the possibly infinite loop will help with lower your `CPU Usage`.

It is not a good idea to have a script run infinitely until it is successful, since an error that is present in the first 100 iterations of a loop, is unlikely to ever be resolved, thus causing the script to 'freeze' up. More oft than not, it is better to re-evaluate the code that you would like run multiple times in the case of an error, and improve it to properly handle any errors that come its way.

Comment: This is only temporarily, so i will use this until i figure out a solution. I've edited it a bit to my use. thanks

Comment: Great example (the best in this thread), but I don't think the `set_error_handler()` call is absolutely necessary unless you specifically want to catch every PHP notice, warning and syntax error *in addition to* the usual exceptions. A regular try/catch will still catch exceptions thrown from within PHP internal functions, as well as the ones you throw yourself.

Answer (score 12):

Simply :

```
function doSomething($params, $try = 1){
    try{
        //do something
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        if($try <5){
             sleep(10);
             //optionnaly log or send notice mail with $e and $try
             doSomething($params, $try++);
        }
        else{ 
             return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Here is an easy algorithm:

```
$trys = 5;
do {
    try {
        // YOUR CODE
        // YOUR CODE
        // YOUR CODE
        // YOUR CODE
        // YOUR CODE

        break;
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        $trys--;
    }
} while($trys > 0);
```

Also, For infinite trys, Remove the `$trys--` line :)

Answer (score 2):

This library seems cool, it has different backoff strategies you can choose from and keeps you from implementing the retry logic every time.

https://github.com/stechstudio/backoff

A sample code:

```
$result = backoff(function() {
    return doSomeWorkThatMightFail();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't entirely understand why you would want to, as there is a good chance you will create an infinite loop. However, if the code is likely to succeed after a small sleep, for whatever reason, below is a solution

```
while(true){
    // execute the code you are attempting
    if(some condition to signal success){
        break; // exit the loop
    }

    sleep(2); // 2 seconds
}
```

Comment: Retrying after sleep (but normally with a maximum number of attempts to avoid infinite loops) is very common when dealing with external services, that may be down

Comment: This is just retry on condition. I think the main request is how to retry with the try catch ? Only checking a certain condition is certainly far from what try catch that prevents all exception.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this library: PHP Backoff

It allows them to execute a code, if for some reason something happens and fails, it is automatically rerun as a task. It has several configurations so you can adapt it to your needs.

**Instalalation:**

```
composer require stechstudio/backoff
```

**Quickstart**

```
$result = backoff(function() {
    // Here is the function they want to execute.
    return doSomeWorkThatMightFail();
});
```

**All documentation is here:** https://github.com/stechstudio/backoff

Answer (score 0):

There is a very elegant solution embedded in Laravel for this type of problem, that can easily be ported to any php framework/project.

It uses a control-structure goto to go circle back to before the exception happend to run the code again, unless conditions are met.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php

More information:
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#method-retry

```
function retry($times, callable $callback, $sleepMilliseconds = 0, $when = null)
    {
        $attempts = 0;

        $backoff = [];

        if (is_array($times)) {
            $backoff = $times;

            $times = count($times) + 1;
        }

        beginning:
        $attempts++;
        $times--;

        try {
            return $callback($attempts);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            if ($times < 1 || ($when && ! $when($e))) {
                throw $e;
            }

            $sleepMilliseconds = $backoff[$attempts - 1] ?? $sleepMilliseconds;

            if ($sleepMilliseconds) {
                usleep(value($sleepMilliseconds, $attempts, $e) * 1000);
            }

            goto beginning;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

To be able to catch an exception you have to first throw one. 
Something like this.

```
<?php
function inverse($x) {
    if (!$x) {
        throw new Exception('Division by zero.');
    }
    return 1/$x;
}

try {
    echo inverse(5) . "\n";
    echo inverse(0) . "\n";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}

// Continue execution
echo "Hello World\n";
?>
```

There are certain built in exceptions : http://php.net/manual/en/spl.exceptions.php