# PHP try, catch, and try again (depending on output)?

Tags: php, class, exception, try-catch

I currently have the following PHP which uses a try/catch block checking for exceptions.

```
try {
    $obj->login('User', 'Pass');
    $obj->joinServer('Server');
} catch(ConnectionException $objException){
    die();
}
```

...and this is the ConnectionException class:

```
class ConnectionException extends Exception {

    public function __construct($strError, $intError, $mixOther = null){
        $this->strError = $strError;
        $this->intError = $intError;

        echo $this->intError, ' - ', $this->strError, chr(10);
    }

}
```

Now let's say if the "catch" part returns a specific error (if `ConnectionException` outputs a specific message), how can I "retry" the try/catch again?

Comment: Here is a more popular related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25002164/470749

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can nest the `try/catch`, wrap it the code into a function to avoid code repetition:

```
function login($obj){
    $obj->login('User', 'Pass');
    $obj->joinServer('Server');
}


try {
    login($obj);
} catch(ConnectionException $objException){
    try {
        login($obj);
    } catch(ConnectionException $objException){
        die();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this at this level, instead of having it throw a `ConnectionException` every time, throw a different exception that's a subclass of `ConnectionException` that signifies when you would want to rerun the logic. Then, encapsulate the logic that you have within the `try` to a function, and call it again.

```
try {
    doWork( $obj);
} catch( ConnectionTimeoutException $e) {
    // Wait a bit, then retry
    try {
        sleep(10);
        doWork( $obj);
    } catch( ConnectionException $e) {
        // Because of the subclass, this would catch both ConnectionException and ConnectionTimeoutException
        die();
    }
} catch( ConnectionException $e) {
    die();
}
```

You can also change how you're calling this function, and call it twice depending on the result of `ConnectionException`. Although, in that manner, it may make more sense to base this decision on a return value instead of an Exception.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to create a simple while loop that checks for a condition:

```
    try_connection = true;
    while(try_connection) {
      try {
        $obj->login('User', 'Pass');
        $obj->joinServer('Server');
      } catch(ConnectionException $objException){
        if(!specific_message)
          try_connection = false;
      }
    }
```