# Retry a try/catch when it fails

Tags: php

I've tried a few different try/catch loops to try and solve problems automatically but they always seem to cause the software to die.

```
$doLoop = true;

while ($doLoop) {

    try {
        //do a thing
        insertIntoDb($data);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        //try again
        insertIntoDb($data);
        //write error to file
        writeError($e);
    }
}
```

Here's my original try/catch.

The issue is sometimes the MySQL server 'goes away' and I need to catch that exception and keep retrying until it comes back.

What can I change here to get this to keep retrying until successful?

Comment: you were pretty close to the solution :)

Comment: I'd implore you to look into _why_ your MySQL server "goes away." One definition of insanity is trying the same thing over and over again while expecting different results.

Comment: If your db sometimes "goes away" then your solution shouldn't be to keep retrying in PHP, it should be to fix the connectivity issue. This code is an infinite loop waiting to happen.

Comment: Sjagr, it's an issue we don't currently have control over. And I'm logging the exceptions so we can use it to show our host what's happening and finally get them to fix it.

Comment: Here is a more popular related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25002164/470749

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use a break as last statement in your `try` block to leave the loop only on success.

But you should also limit the number of retries by using a `for` loop instead.
Otherwise, your code might run in an infinite loop:

```
// limit the number of retries to 3 retries to avoid endless looping
for ($i=1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
    try {
        // do something
        insertIntoDb($data);
        // leave loop only if above statement succeeds
        break;
    } 
    catch (Exception $e) {
        writeError($e);
    }
    // sleep 200ms to give the MySQL server time to come back up
    usleep(200000);
}
```

Also note the `usleep()` call:

This is important because otherwise the PHP process would take all resources (100% CPU) while retrying as fast as possible. You can adjust the value to fit your needs. (maybe 200ms is too long or too short in your case)

Also note that you may need to reconnect to the MySQL DB on failure! I did not include code for that case in my example.

Answer (score 2):

This will only work, if your function `insertIntoDb` will throw an Exception. If you use mysql* functions, then it won't work.

After `insertIntoDb($data);` you should set `$doLoop = false`

Comment: If you're passing PDO's exception then yes. Your function `insertIntoDb()` should not contain a try-catch